# How to make a preliminary panel data fixed effect regression analysis

Tags: r, panel, plm

For my bachelor thesis I am researching the impact that demographic changes have on the economy.

I compiled data from 12 different variables, and made a panel data. You can download it here :[Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15rNSzgQPr2IloGnYyeiDt_V1WkXBeWWH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105718224167684549964&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Data should look like this:

[image]

I want to run some very easy model and see the summary.

`fixed_model = plm(GDPpCap_Growth_Rate ~ Old_Dependancy_Ratio + Fertility_Rate,  data = Panel_dataset, index = c("Country Name", "Year"), model = "within")`

`summary(fixed_model)`

However this code doesnt work for me, i did download packages such as plm.

The error code:

```
Error in pdata.frame(data, index) : variable Country Name does not exist (individual index)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Run `names(Panel_dataset)[1] <- "Country_Name"` and then change your code above to `index = c("Country_Name", "Year")`. The tl;dr is that spaces in variable names create problems.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem! However if I press enter the Rstudio completely crashes, the calculation wont stop. Never had this issue before, I have a very fast laptop. Also the new model wont even register in my data environment (top right) Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: i would first run the script outside of R Studio. That is, open R itself, and copy and paste your script in to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Problem solved Phil, I had to update some packages. Works fine now! Thank you for your time!